# Criteria to list of Entityinstance+Extrafield

Tags: hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

im pretty sure this question anywhere already has been asked anywhere - didnt found the answer.

I got an simple Criteria like this:

```
s.createCriteria(Human.class).list()
```

gives me an resultlist of entityinstance of Human (gender and name).

**Can i add an calculation like "salutation"** to the resulting entityinstances only (without changing Human.java) and avoid the creation of an 2-dimensional array?

I know, this should be the job of such an Decorator-Class, is there any workaround? The enlarged entityinstance should extends the Human-class!

Comment: It's possible with Hibernate [`SQLQuery`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/SQLQuery.html) - look for `addEntity()` and `addScalar()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not completely possible. A Criteria query can only return entities, arrays of scalars, or value objects built from scalars (using a `ResultTransformer`).

You could return a list of `HumanWithSalutation` objects, which would hold the same fields as a Human + an additional salutation one, but these would be value objects, and not persistent objects: any modification made to these objects would not be made persistent to the database as it would be with Human instances.

To do that, create the class :

```
public class HumanWithSalutation extends Human {
    private String salutation;

    // getter and setter
}
```

Assign it an `AliasToBeanResultTransformer` (which will populate all your `HumanWithSalutation` objects using setters), and make sure the criteria has a projection list returning all the fields of Human + the salutation (aliased to "salutation"):

```
ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
projectionList.add(Projections.property("id");
projectionList.add(Projections.property("name");
projectionList.add(Projections.property("gender");
projectionList.add(Projections.alias(Projections.sqlProjection(...), "salutation"));
criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
```

If you don't want the SQL projection, you could implement the transformation in Java in the `getSalutation()` method (and remove the setter).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property with `@Formula` mapping into the `Human` class, if you are happy with `@Formula` eager fetching.

Or if you need this property to be fetched lazily, then make an extra entity on the same table as `Human` class

```
@Entity
@Table("HUMAN")
@Immutable
public class HumanWithSalutation extends Human {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Formula("(select ...)")
    private String salutation;

    // getter and setter
}
```

and then map it from `Human` by `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` with `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`.